# overridelibrary in android studio

Tags: android

I had two packages in my purchased app and when I run them, this message appears to me. I don't know how I can get rid of "override library"

> Error:Execution failed for task ':hDWallPaperWithAdmob:processDebugManifest'.
>   Error: [/Users/omar/Downloads/HDWallPaperWithAdmob/hDWallPaperWithAdmob/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:9] Invalid instruction 'overridelibrary', valid instructions are : REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT

I purchased this app and I can attach link to download it.

Answer (score 1):

To override it you need to add tools:overrideLibrary with the package name in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="library package name"/>
```

For eg:- For google play services use as below

```
   <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all"/>
   --------------------------------
   --------------------------------
```

**tools:overrideLibrary marker**

> A special marker that can only be used with uses-sdk declaration to
>   override importing a library which minimum SDK version is more recent
>   than that application's minimum SDK version. Without such a marker,
>   the manifest merger will fail. The marker will allow users to select
>   which libraries can be imported ignoring the minimum SDK version.

Also it seems your project has an old gradle version, try updating the gradle.

Comment: i copied this <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all"/>

to every package i have "cropper"-"hdwallpaperwithAdMob"
but error still appear
and i don't know which library should i write for every package

Comment: No you dont have paste what i mentioned, that was just an example..you have to paste the package name of the library you want to override